# Accessing to all sms messages on a device in Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

In the Smartface we can get the last sms when it comes, but I want to get all the sms messages saved on the device.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to reach to the older sms messages. 
In order to reach to the sms content, you should use the `Global_Events_onSMSReceived` event, and this only runs when there is a new message.

Also, reading the latest sms is only valid for Android, iOS doesn't let you to read the content of the any message.

You can check the link below for more information : 
http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/device/telephony/